# How to add Floating Action button with appcompact

Tags: android, android-xml, floating-action-button

i recently updated by android sdk to new android 5.0 
and was trying to add Floating action button (FAB) using appcompact..

i dont want to use any type of external libraries

How can i add FAB button to by project with appcompact

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any special libraries to make a FAB. Make a class that extends ImageButton and in the onTouch method, scale your view up and down.

Answer (score 1):

android now has the floating action button on their design:

just add `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'` on your gradle file and add

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@mipmap/icon_plus_button"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/mainContent"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:backgroundTint="#5894EF"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>
```

on your xml layout. Hope this helps anyone.